# Laravel relations across different databases

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am currently trying to do the following in a Laravel 5.4 project

```
$this->belongsToMany(Module::class,'platform_modules_acquired', 'platform_id', 'module_id');
```

Now the `module` class pulls from a table in the `admin` database while the table `platform_modules_acquired` is in the `clients` database. When I try to run the above code I get an error saying `platform_modules_acquired` table can't be found in the `admin` database.

I tried changing the above request by saying that the table is `clients.platform_modules_acquired` but still not finding the table. Also I tried appending `->using('PlatformModules::class')` but still getting the same error...

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'admin.plataformas_modulos_contratados' doesn't exist (SQL: select 'module' from 'modules' inner join 'platform_modules_acquired' on 'modules'.'id' = 'platform_modules_acquired'.'module_id' where 'platform_modules_acquired'.'platform_id' = 187)
```

How could I go about telling this relation to look in the `clients` database for the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a connection inside the relation like this:

```
$this->belongsToMany(Module::class,'clients.platform_modules_acquired', 'platform_id', 'module_id');
```

Comment: can I use the connection name declared in my `config/database.php` file or do I have to use the actual name of the database on the server?

Comment: Connection name.

Comment: @natral did that work? Sorry I was brushing teeth ;)

Comment: tried both but the connection name didn't work, had to use the name of the database to get it to work. Would have preferred to use the connection name since this would make the method more independent but will look into it further and see what solution I can find. Thanks for the help

Comment: found a work around by using `env()` function to read the table name defined in my env file. I prefer this tan hard coding the database name into the models since this can change down the line. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @natral it's better practice to prevent the use of `env()` in your code, because when you use `config:cache` the env is empty. You could use the `config()` helper instead to use either a new config key, or an existing one from the database.php config file. Good luck.